# C# How to make code clean by storing console.writeline messages centrally

Tags: c#

I am a beginner programmer and creating a c# application. I have several console.writeline messages.

The problem is all the string passed in console.writeline looks so nasty in the code.

Can someone please tell me what's the best method to store the strings/messages centrally.

This way the code looks cleaner and I don't have so many strings in the code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want just to clean your code, move this strings to some separate class (Constants or Messages) kind of the following:

```
    public static class Constants
    {
        public static readonly string SomeMessage = "Hello world!";

        public static readonly string OtherMessage = "Goodbye world!";

        ...
    }
```

and then use them:

```
Console.WriteLine(Constants.SomeMessage);
```

Comment: +1. Using resources and auto-generated constants is next steps with this approach.

Comment: Is this the standard way?  Do you mean like a resx file. Do you have anymore info?

Comment: @user1526912 yes. it's the standard way. you can use resx file. or you can store some values in appSettings section of your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your looking at here, but may be you could create a list of strings?

```
static List<string> myList = new List<string> { "string1", "string2" };
console.writeline(myList[0]);
```

Comment: I think it is bad idea - there is no way to guess if myList[4] or myList[17] is correct string for any particular statement.

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods could be fun for this. It's not a standard pattern, but it's less typing. When writing to the console you might be getting into logging and should be considering log4net or NLog.

```
// Extension Method example

public static class ConstantExtensions
{
       public static void WriteToConsole(this string constant)
       {
          Console.WriteLine(constant);
       }

}

public static class Constants
{
    public static readonly string SomeMessage = "Hello world!";

    public static readonly string OtherMessage = "Goodbye world!";

    ...
}

Constants.SomeMessage.WriteToConsole();
```